# How to add GWT addon for Spring Roo 2.0

Tags: spring, gwt, spring-roo

I am using Spring Roo 2.0 and I am not able to add GWT addon. These have got moved to Spring Roo community but I am not able to find the repository URL to download the add ons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GWT add-on has not been migrated to 2.0 version yet (see [pom.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-roo-community-addons/blob/master/addon-gwt/pom.xml#L7)).

If you or your organization are interested to do it look at the [community add-on repository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-roo-community-addons).

Comment: Thanks for the update. Is there a way of downgrading my application which I developed using Roo 2.0 to 1.xxx version?

Comment: Sorry, I think there isn't any automatic way to do it. The easy way could be execute the log.roo file (rename it first)  generated by Roo in project folder in a new folder using Roo 1.x. Good luck!